# Selecting HTML dropdown with ReactJS in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, reactjs, web-scraping

I'm trying to use VBA to select a dropdown item from an HTML website that uses ReactJS.  For this example, we can use the following website:

https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

```
<span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2--value-item">New South Wales</span>
```

If an HTML page lists all the select options on the dropdown, I can easily set the `elementID` to one of the dropdown values.

```vb
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    'with for page load
    ieWaitForURL

    .Navigate "https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/"

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("react-select-2--value-item").Value = "Victoria"
```

But the HTML of the ReactJS website doesn't list all the options of the dropdown, and the value of the innertext changes as I make a different selection.

Is there a way to select from a ReactJS dropdown using VBA if all the options aren't listed in the HTML?

Comment: Is selenium vba an option?

Comment: Sure! Any idea how to do it with selenium vba?

Comment: Thank you so much!  Let me give it a shot.

Comment: I tried following the steps below, but I'm very new to selenium VBA and don't have much experience with java script unfortunately.  How can I identify the javascript that has the range of possible values?  I used this website as an example, but I'll have to apply what I learn to a different secure website.  Also, if you get a chance, could you please translate the python script to VBA?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: We may have to spend some time in a stackoverflow chat room discussing this as I will have to walk you through the steps I would take and you will need to lead me somewhat blindly as I won’t be able to test with the actual site.

Comment: I was able to test your code below with Chrome and it works great!  How would I do this with IE?  Is there an IE driver that I would need to place inside the selenium folder?

Comment: I tried accepting the answer, but it won't allow me to change it publicly with less than 15 reputation points.  I will certainly accept this as an answer as soon as I gain reputation.  Thanks again!

Comment: QHarr, how did you know that the css element was ".Select-menu div"?  I tried searching the html but didn't find that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a lot easier than I thought. The following uses selenium basic. Install [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0), ensure latest chromedriver.exe is in selenium folder, vbe > tools > references > add reference to selenium type library

I show grabbing all the option values into a dictionary. Also, selecting an item from the dropdown.

The key here is that the option menu is not a traditional `select` element, with child `option`s,  but uses [React Select](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/). The range of possible values are pulled via Ajax from [this script](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/app.js).

I show how you could also retrieve the possible values from that script direct, at the end, using python, but am happy to translate to vba if you really are interested. Once the dropdown is clicked the list of available values can be collected.

If you want to go down the IE route you can use the same approach but need to trigger the events that will open the dropdown. These are also detailed in the js 
script I think.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim d As WebDriver, i As Long, dropDownOptions As Object
    Const URL = "https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/"

    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Set dropDownOptions = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .FindElementByCss("button:nth-of-type(2)").Click
        .FindElementByCss(".Select-arrow-zone").ClickAndHold

        Dim item As Object
        For Each item In .FindElementsByCss(".Select-menu div") 'put list of options in dictionary
            dropDownOptions(item.Text) = i
            i = i + 1
        Next

        For Each item In .FindElementsByCss(".Select-menu div") 'loop to select an option
            If item.Text = "Victoria" Then       'If item.Text = dropDownOptions.item(3)  etc....
                item.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Python script to parse possible dropdown values from json:

This shows the 3 different element parts which are updated through the dropdown (labels, classes and values)

```py
import requests
import re
import json

r = requests.get('https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/app.js')
s = str(r.content)
p1 = re.compile('t\.AU=(.*)')
p2 = re.compile('.+?(?=,\[\d+\])')
data1 = re.findall(p1, s)[0]
data2 = re.findall(p2, data1)[0].replace(',disabled:!0','')

replacements = ['value:','label:','className:']

for item in replacements:
    data2 = re.sub(item, '"' + item[:-1] + '":' , data2)

finals = data2.split(',t.US=')
finalAus = json.loads(finals[0])
# finalUs = json.loads(finals[1])

d = {}
i = 0
for item in finalAus:
    d[item['label']] = i
    # item['label']
    # item['value']
    # item['className']
    i+=1

print(d)
```

Comment: Let me know if you need help with this